# How to disable a button within a anyObject Button in swift

Tags: swift, button

Ok so I want to be able to disable the button within itself. So when I press the button it will disable itself.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func but(_ sender: AnyObject) {
//this code doesn't seem to work at all, and I don't know why
        (sender as AnyObject).isEnabled = false
    }
   
}
```

It gives me an error message when ever I try to do this "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '@lvalue Bool?'"

So is there a different way I can disable this button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the button I use this code

```
@IBAction func but(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        var disableMyButton = sender as? UIButton
        disableMyButton?.isEnabled = false
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you've hooked up this `IBAction` in Interface Builder to a `UIButton`. So, you can change your function signature to:

```
@IBAction func but(_ sender: UIButton) {
  sender.isEnabled = false
}
```

`AnyObject` doesn't have a property called `isEnabled`, which is why your previous code failed.